# stop label from toggling the input checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html code. When clicking on the label it toggles the checkbox.

```
<td><label for="startClientFromWebEnabled">Client Launch From Web:</label></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="startClientFromWebEnabled" name="startClientFromWebEnabled" data-bind="checked: StartClientFromWebEnabled, enable: IsEditable" onchange="startClientFromWebToggleRequiredAttribute()" /></td>
```

How can I prevent this? If I remove the `for="startClientFromWebEnabled"`, It stops toggling but I need this because I have some logic that takes the id from the element that fires the event ...

Comment: Can I reformat your HTML for better readability? Also please recheck the code. I'm not sure it should contain something like `ty'enter code here'pe="checkbox`.

Comment: Remove `for` attribute but leave an `id`.

Comment: @dfsq he's already stated he can't do that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**The best solution** would be to let label toggle the checkbox as that is intuitive and expected behaviour.

**Second best** solution is to make sure your checkbox is not nested inside label and label does not have `for` attribute. If you have some logic that depends on it, you can put data attributes on elements and use those in your logic.

```html
<input type="checkbox" data-myid="1" />
<label data-myid="1">foo</label>
```

**Last resort**

You could prevent the default behaviour of the `click` event using jQuery:

```
$('label[for="startClientFromWebEnabled"]').click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
});​
```

Please see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wNMVu/) for an example.

Comment: I'll share my experience. My input was a complex autocomplete input with a clear button and it was breaking things because when you clicked an item in the dropdown list it would simultaneously click on the clear button and would pick an item and then immediately remove it. In the end I decided to just leave the label but make it not linked to the input, since it was originally wrapping everything. It seems better than a span but I didn't want to use stopPropagation or preventDefault and I didn't want to set the `for=id` because my framework made it annoying to pass the id.

Answer (score 11):

There is CSS solution too:

```
label {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I should have tried this first, it makes more sense for me, and one doesn't have to apply it to all labels if they don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using JQuery, add an `id` on your label then
add this in your script:

```
$("#lbl").click(function(){
   return false; 
});
```

Comment: It's better to intercept the event and prevent the default action, as that's all we *need* to do here. `return false` does more than that, and could cause unexpected results elsewhere, particularly with propagation.

Comment: Also, there's no need to add an ID to the label (please see my answer for the selector).

Comment: I'm also a noob in jquery, so im just giving an answer to what @Mdb is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Just prevent default on label or any part of label, if desired.

```js
document.querySelector('.prevent-default').addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
   e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

```html
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" />
    <label class="prevent-default" for="1">foo</label>
```

or

```js
document.querySelector('.prevent-default').addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
   e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

```html
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" />
    <label for="1">foo some part <span class="prevent-default">not</span> clickable</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

"I have some logic that takes the id from the element "

You could remove the `for`-attribute, if you store the ID somewhere else. For example in a `data-*`-attribute:

```
<label data-input-id="startClientFromWebEnabled">
```

On the other hand, it is sometimes difficult to point and click an a check-box based on the styling and the capabilities of the user. There is are good reasons for using the `for`-attribute.