# On clicking on label textbox is getting selected?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am facing some abnormal behavior in my MVC application. I have taken textbox and label in my View

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AddressLine1)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddressLine1, new { maxlength = 40, title = "Enter Address Line1" })
```

and in my ViewModel

```
[DisplayName("Address Line1")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Address Line1")]
public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
```

at the time of debugging when I am clicking on label, textbox is getting selected. Someone please help me to solve and please tell me why I am facing such kind of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is standard behavior for label:

> The `<label>` tag defines a label for an  element.
>
> The `<label>` element does not render as anything special for the user.
>   However, it provides a usability improvement for mouse users, because
>   if the user clicks on the text within the `<label>` element, it toggles
>   the control.

Comment: can I stop this behavior? if yes then how? please tell me

Comment: Do not use label: `<span>@m.AddressLine1</span>` instead of `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AddressLine1)` for example.

Comment: at the time of Edit, label is getting change to textbox value

Comment: Right, leave then `LabelFor` and use this solution to stop labels selecting controls: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12912480/2043144

Comment: Then just hardcore it: `<span>Address Line1</span>` this will work 100% and won't do anything. Only drawback is you have to update html directly and not attributes in `ViewModel`