# Custom checkbox - stop ability to check box by clicking label

Tags: html, css

I have a checkbox. It looks like this.

[image]

It works fine... except that you can check the box by clicking the label. This is problematic for two reasons:

1. I don't like it
2. I need the user to be able to click the blue link. Right now, it just checks the box

Here is my current HTML:

```
 <label className="container">I have read and do accept <a href={props.link}>{props.topic}</a>
    <input type="checkbox" onChange={event => props.onChange(event)}/>
    <span className="checkmark"></span>
 </label>
```

Here is my css, which came (roughly) from here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_custom_checkbox

```
/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: 0;
    height: 21px;
    width: 21px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: rgb(29, 29, 29);
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
    left: 8px;
    top: 4px;
    width: 4px;
    height: 9px;
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Any thoughts? You can actually play with it in the W3C pen I provided.

Comment: I believe the basic problem is having the `<input type="checkbox" />` inside the `<label>` - is that really a requirement for you?

Comment: No. But when I put it outside, even when I replace the "container" wrapper, the checkbox becomes unclickable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912236/stop-label-from-toggling-the-input-checkbox

Answer (score 1):

```
.container {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.checkmark {
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.container a {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Comment: This is soooooo close! If I turn .container a {
    pointer-events: auto;
} on, it does the click of the check box instead of the link. But everything else works! I really appreciate that ha!

Comment: What browser are you using? This works for me in Firefox, Chrome and Safari on MacOs https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FRO3DL7UIWS1

Comment: so weird, it works for me in the pen too. I'm in React and it's not doing it there. I can't see what's different. Again, this appears to be the answer. Something is throwing it off...

Comment: Is your React code producing an actual `href`attribute? I can see it breaking if it was missing

Comment: ah ha! You're on to something. When I changed the href to a black string, it sorta worked ha. Except the shading still happens

Comment: If you get an actual link in there and that's still an issue you may just have to move the elements around. Get the checkbox and the link outside of the label element.

Comment: No it works with the link there. You were right. Now the only issue is when you hover over the link, the checkbox also becomes shaded. But the link works. You got me like 90% of the way there man. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can pull the checkbox into it's own container, then, if you want the label to semantically pertain to that specific input, you have to assign it a `for` attribute, and assign a corresponding `id` attribute to the input field. Now, you have the best of both worlds. Link is clickable, while the rest of the label checks the checkbox.

```html
<div class="checkbox-container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
  <span className="checkmark"></span>
</div>
<label class="container" for="checkbox">
  I have read and do accept the <a href="#">terms and conditions</a>
</label>
```

Looks like you've figured out the custom checkbox UI part already, so I'll leave that to you.